# Por qué no me funciona mi bucle for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para realizar la escala mayor de una nota pero no me funciona el bucle, creo que el problema es que se toma el número 0 para sumar en cada iteración pero la variable que almacena el numero 0 no cambia su valor, lo que debería hacer es que en la primera iteración la variable debe cambiar a 2 en la segunda a 4 en la tercera a 5 y así.

```js
let notas=['C','c#','D','d#','E','F','f#','G','g#','A','a#','B'];
let notausuario="";
let formula=[2,2,1,2,2,2,1];

function capturarnota(){
  let notausuario=document.getElementById("nota").value;
  let posicion=notas.indexOf(notausuario);
      for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        let posicion=+formula[i];
      let posicion1=notas[posicion];
      console.log(posicion1);

    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="programa.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="nota">
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="capturarnota();">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar qué resultado debería dar la escala si el comienzo es en RE (D) por ejemplo? La frase "la primera iteración la variable debe cambiar a 2 en la segunda a 4 en la tercera a 5 y así" creo que puede quedar un poco ambigua

Comment: Solo necesito que posicion vaya cambiando su valor el problema está en que en cada iteración toma el valor inicial de posicion cuando debería cambiar su valor conforme a cada iteración, por ejemplo en el bucle pongo que se tome posicion y se le sume la posición del array formula que es 2,2,1 etc. Pero posición en cada iteración sigue tomando el su valor inicial no el valor que a surgido en la primera iteración

Comment: Uno de los errores que se encuentra es dentro del `for` revisa tu variable `posicion`, puedes agregar unos ejemplos de lo que te gustaría lograr? pues si se presta a muchas confusiones, pues por ejemplo lo que entendi es que al ingresar `D` el resultado que necesitas es `D,E,F`?

Comment: puedes probar a poner varios console.log() en tu codigo para ver que es lo que vale cada uno de tus variables? mas que nada para que te asegures que `notausuario` y `posicion` tengan valores correctos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según estoy entendiendo, lo que intentas hacer es buscar en el array `notas` el valor que introduce el usuario y crear una secuencia de 7 valores incrementandole el valor que esta en el array `formula`.

Si es eso lo que quieres hay varios problemas en tu código:

- El bucle `for` has puesto `let` a la variable
  `posicion` y se esta reiniciando cada vez que entra en el bucle.
- Has puesto al reves el operador de incremento, el correcto es asi: `+=`.
- Si seleccionas la nota **a#** o **B** al
  incrementarle 1 o 2 vas a salirte del los límites del array `notas`.

Teniendo esas dos cosas en cuenta tu código debería de ser algo así:

```js
let notas = ['C', 'c#', 'D', 'd#', 'E', 'F', 'f#', 'G', 'g#', 'A', 'a#', 'B'];
let notausuario = "";
let formula = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1];

function capturarnota() {
  let notausuario = document.getElementById("nota").value;
  let posicion = notas.indexOf(notausuario);
  for (var i = 0; i < formula.length; i++) { 
  
    posicion += formula[i]

    if (posicion >= notas.length) {
      posicion = posicion - notas.length
    }

    let posicion1 = notas[posicion];
    console.log(posicion1);

  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="programa.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="nota">
  </form>
  <input type="button" onclick="capturarnota();" value="Calcular">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente ya debe haber algun algoritmo en S.O o en internet que resuelva este problema.

Propongo esta solución, que aunque tiene mucho verbose y variables hard code, puede funcionar, ya que las notas y escalas musicales son bien conocidas y sus estructuras lógicas no van a cambiar. Además, es un código muy inteligible si eres principiante.

```js
function conjuntoDeNotas(){
    const nota = document.getElementById("nota").value;
    //aqui tendrias que capturar otro valor donde 
    //el usuario te indique que tipo de escala M / m tipoDeEscala
    //formulas pentatonicas Mayor
    //tono, tono, semitono, tono, tono, tono
    let formulaTonalMayor=[0,2,4,5,7,9,11];
    //menor
    //tono, semitono, tono, tono, semitono, tono
    //Aqui tendrias que crear casos para cada nota mayor y menor
    //podrias concatenar lo que hay en nota con tipoDeEscala
    //var tipoDeNota = nota + tipoDeEscala
    //y este valor tipoDeNota enviarlo como la nota del switch
    switch (nota) {
        case 'C':
            //Aqui por ejemplo tipoDeNota seria CM en el case, en vez de C
            let notasCM=['C','c#','D','d#','E','F','f#','G','g#','A','a#','B'];
            crearEscala(notasCM, formulaTonalMayor);
          break;
        case 'A':
            //Aqui por ejemplo tipoDeNota seria AM en el case, en vez de A
            let notasAM=['A','a#','B','C','c#','D','d#','E','F','f#','G','g#'];
            crearEscala(notasAM, formulaTonalMayor);
            break;
        default:
          console.log(`No existe la Nota ${nota}.`);
      }
}

function crearEscala(notas, formula){
    let escala = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        escala.push(notas[formula[i]])
    }
    console.log(escala);
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="nota">
    </form>
    <button onclick="conjuntoDeNotas();">Dame la escala Mayor DO/Mayor La</button>
```

Este ejemplo solo funciona para escala Mayor Do y escala Mayor La

Si decides usar esta propuesta, ten en mente que debes crear todos los casos restantes del switch para cada nota, tanto Mayor y menor, junto con las estructuras Tonales de las mismas (Sostenidos y bemoles), es decir los arrays. Por ejemplo para **Fa Mayor**, el array debe tener **bemol** y así.

Además, debes ingeniartelas para cuando lleges a la etapa en que el usuario pase también, un valor para identificar si se quiere crear una escala Mayor o menor (un radio button podría ser).

Si decides ir por el algoritmo, lo que se me ocurre es tomar la nota inicial como apuntador y trasnversar todo el arreglo de notas, después usando lógica, armar la estructura tonal correspondiente, para finalmente crear la escala deseada. Suena como a Quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he probado y lo hace correctamente.
Te puedo dar una explicación y creo que es lo que te ha pasado porque me ha dado la impresión de que no realiza el FOR correctamente.
Lo que me ha pasado es que en la consola de Chrome es que lo elementos repetidos no los muestra. Pone un número delante indicando las veces. Puedes comprobar que el FOR funciona con un alert como te pongo de ejemplo:

```
let notas=['C','c#','D','d#','E','F','f#','G','g#','A','a#','B'];
let notausuario="";
let formula=[2,2,1,2,2,2,1];

function capturarnota(){
  let a="";
  let notausuario=document.getElementById("nota").value;
  let posicion=notas.indexOf(notausuario);
      for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     posicion=+formula[i];
      posicion1=notas[posicion%7];
      console.log(posicion1+i);
      a+=posicion1;
    }
    alert(a);
};
```

El `%7` que he añadido es para que no se te salga del limite del array.

Espero que haberte ayudado